# Highlighting a bloc of string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm

How can I highlight a bloc of string?
my problem here I want to highlight all the words `a reference` in one bloc 
like this image

[image]

When I have words that inside `""` DOUBLE QUOTES  `var wordsToHighlight =' "word1, word2" '` means highlight word1 word2 in the whole text

my problem here needs to highlight the text that inside double quotes in the whole text

Explication:

The * its a truncation and works well

the ? to highlight words+ n characters

```js
var row = {
  "Abstract": "a reference I have a reference server for reference and just a server here server test." 
};

var wordsToHighlight = `reference  "a reference"  reference jus? fo* `;
var result = row["Abstract"];

  
var words=wordsToHighlight ;
var resultAbstract = row["Abstract"];
var wordsTH2=[], m;
var rx = /["“']([^"”']+)["”']|\S+/g;
while (m=rx.exec(words)) {
  if (m[1]) {
     var arr = m[1].trim().split(/\s*,\s*/);
     for (var i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
        wordsTH2.push(arr[i]);
     }
  } else {
    wordsTH2.push(m[0]);
  }
}
//sort wordsTH2 by length in a descending order
wordsTH2.sort(function(a, b){
  return b.length - a.length;
});
wordsTH2.forEach(function (word) {
word = word.replace(/\*/g, '\\S*').replace(/\?/g, '.');
//<span style="background-color:yellow;">.*?</span>|  it will match terms that are already highlighted and won't touch them since if it matches, Group 1 and 2 are undefined and if Group 1 and 2 match, a term ($2) will get wrapped with the new span

resultAbstract = resultAbstract.replace(new RegExp('<span style="background-color:yellow;">.*?</span>|(\\s|^)(' + word + ')(?=\\s|$)', "gi"),function ($0, $1, $2) { return $1 ? $1 + '<span style="background-color:yellow;">' + $2 + '</span>' : $0; });
});
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = resultAbstract;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `(\\s|^)` and the subsequent check for Group 1. When `^` (start of string) is matched, the `$1` variable still evaluates to *false*, and the replacement with the whole value happens.

It seems to make more sense to check if Group 2 matched, replace `return $1 ?` with `return $2 ?` since Group 2 cannot be empty or null/undefined:

```js
var row = {
  "Abstract": "a reference I have a reference server for reference and just a server here server test." 
};

var wordsToHighlight = `reference  "a reference"  reference jus? fo* `;
var result = row["Abstract"];

  
var words=wordsToHighlight ;
var resultAbstract = row["Abstract"];
var wordsTH2=[], m;
var rx = /["“']([^"”']+)["”']|\S+/g;
while (m=rx.exec(words)) {
  if (m[1]) {
     var arr = m[1].trim().split(/\s*,\s*/);
     for (var i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
        wordsTH2.push(arr[i]);
     }
  } else {
    wordsTH2.push(m[0]);
  }
}
//sort wordsTH2 by length in a descending order
wordsTH2.sort(function(a, b){
  return b.length - a.length;
});
wordsTH2.forEach(function (word) {
word = word.replace(/\*/g, '\\S*').replace(/\?/g, '.');
resultAbstract = resultAbstract.replace(new RegExp('<span style="background-color:yellow;">.*?</span>|(\\s|^)(' + word + ')(?=\\s|$)', "gi"),function ($0, $1, $2) { return $2 ? $1 + '<span style="background-color:yellow;">' + $2 + '</span>' : $0; });
});
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = resultAbstract;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```